# I'm trying to go to main activity through get started layout type button

Tags: java, android-studio

```
package com.example.portfolioapplication.Activity;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import com.example.portfolioapplication.R;



public class IntroActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ConstraintLayout startBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_intro);

        startBtn= (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.startBtn);
        startBtn.setOnClickListener(view -> startActivity(new Intent(IntroActivity.this, MainActivity.class)));


    }
}
```

I'm trying to go to main activity through get started layout type button but my is always crashing when I click to get started

Comment: It's helpful to include the logcat stack trace in your post - but one brief look at the code I'd say you can't cast a `Button` to a `ConstraintLayout` - assuming `R.id.startBtn` is in fact a button - include your `activity_intro` layout xml as well.

Comment: Change  ConstraintLayout to Button

Answer (score 0):

Check IntroActivity is in AndroidManifest.xml . It might be the common issue "ActivityNotFoundException"

```xml
    <activity android:name=".IntroActivity"/>
```